# Cross uniqueness model validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, models

I have a model where I want columns to contain different ids. So a user may follow another user, but not follow themselves.

Migration

```
class CreateFollows < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :follows do |t|
      t.integer :follower_id
      t.integer :followee_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Model

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :followee, class_name: 'User'

  validates :follower_id, uniqueness: { scope: :followee_id }
end
```

But my test seems to fail

Test

```
it 'cannot follow itself' do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  follow = FactoryGirl.create(:follow, follower: user, followee: user)
  expect(follow).to be_invalid
end
```

Output

```
Failures:

1) Follow cannot follow itself
 Failure/Error: expect(follow).to be_invalid
   expected `#<Follow id: 27, follower_id: 78, followee_id: 78, created_at: "2014-07-04 02:20:59", updated_at: "2014-07-04 02:20:59">.invalid?` to return true, got false
 # ./spec/models/follow_spec.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

From everything I've read, this looks write. Anyone have any pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This validation:

```
validates :follower_id, uniqueness: { scope: :followee_id }
```

simply says that the set of `follower_id`s for each `followee_id` cannot contain duplicates (i.e. you can't follow one person twice), it says nothing about `followee_id` being different from `follower_id`.

If you want to disallow following yourself then you have to say so:

```
  validate :cant_follow_yourself

private

  def cant_follow_yourself
    return if followee_id != follower_id
    # add an appropriate error message here...
  end
```