# Devise Model inherit from another devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating an online real estate platform which facilitates (normal) Users and Real Estate agencies. This platform has following user types:

- **Normal Users:** can search houses for rent/purchase, reviews agencies
  etc.
- **Agencies:** can upload posts for house rent/sell etc
- **Employee:** works for a Agencies
- **Super Admin:** manages the site
- **Team Member:** manages portions of the site delegated by Super Admin

Each user type then has different fields (4 - 6 additional fields each). Normal Users and Agencies can self-register. Employees and Admins can be registered by Agencies and Super Admins respectively. Furthermore there are some different multiple roles for a user type (which is not relevant to discuss for this case).

Currently, I have three different devise models (User, Agencies & Super Admin). They have different login and registration forms but share same session [Reference: [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models]][1] User has facility to register via social media (OmniAuth) but Agency must has to register via private Email Id. And Admins will only be registered by Super Admins.

**Here comes requirement [PROBLEM]:**

The following fields are what I've identified as being shared between the three user types above: `Email address & Username` They must be unique for all cases. For example, if an agency has a username then user can't register with same username. At the moment, we are not meeting above requirement as we have different tables/models for different type of user.

**MY PLAN**

Now, since these are all really different users who interact with different sections of the application, so it feels clean to have three different devise models. Therefore, what I think is to create a parent devise model which should be inherited by all type of user models. This way can help me to solve my problem. But now, I'm not confident that how can I inherit parent devise model and use it for my case.

Second option is to use STI (Single Table Inheritance). But my major concern with this approach is that it will create mess with registration and security things.

Now here is my problem with my researched options. What would you recommend me to chose. Moreover, it'd be great if you put an example for elaboration.

P.s. I am inclined to the first one option as I have already done with three different models and their login/registration stuff. :)

Comment: why do you want the devise model to inherit from another devise model?

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas I just edited my question statement. Please have a look on it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how your going to accomplish this without a roles system.. I suppose you could namespace or scope it out but wouldnt be the most secure to keep access to a specific user group.. atleast in my oppinion.

You could Use Single Table Inheritance (STI)..

Essentially you could do something like this (if i understand you correctly)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 # MASTER
end

class AnotherUser < User
 # Inherits attributes from User Table
end
```

going this route you will need to add `type:string` to your User model.

here are a few reference links:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html
http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/

they helped me when i ventured down the STI path..

For example, In a project I did this like so:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Devise Modules Here
end

class Admin < User

end

class SuperAdmin < User

end
```

now the tricky part I found was creating these users.. i opted to create a controller and a link, so in my app a User is created only by an admin or superadmin, and an admin can only be created by a superadmin

Comment: Well, I read these articles and thought to opt same thing. But in this case, I have to create custom registration methods. Infact I have completed my project but now there is another requirement, that is, to have a unique username for all user types.  This is why I just want to use another approach, that is, creating a parent devise model. But I'm not confident on this approach yet.

Comment: Can a user register on their own? or is a user created by an admin?

Comment: No, It's an open registration form. So, user can register itself.

Comment: so what differentiates a Member from an EndUser? (im just trying to figure out the workflow)

Comment: Well, there are two types of users. EndUser is just a normal user while Member is infact an organisation account. Both types of users can register theirselves. Got it?

Comment: Hate to be the bearer of bad news.. but you will probably need to refactor to STI, to accomplish this. I can't think of another way to do it in all honesty. i don't see how you could validate a unique username across separate models aside from creating it through STI. There may be a way to doit using jQuery or javascript but I'm not advanced enough with either of those.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting your point. Still thinking on other cases. Otherwise I have to opt this method. 
Anyway, thanks man for your help.

Comment: i just found this you may be able to modify it to your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565883/cross-uniqueness-model-validation-in-rails Best of luck with your project @MuhammadAteeqAzam